# How to solve $kx=e^x$

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

How do I solve equations of the form $kx=e^x$ for $x$?

E.g. how would I solve $3x=e^x$?

---

I have tried using logs

$$
\begin{align*}
3x&=e^x \\
\ln3x&=x\\
\ln3+\ln{x}&=x\\
x-\ln{x}&=\ln3
\end{align*}
$$

but it doesn't look like this is going to get me anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

This kind of equation has no solution in terms of elementary functions. You have to use the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), which is effectively defined to be the solution of this sort of problem.